# Payment apps are not showing in my Samsung and Vivo devices while integrating UPI Payment gateway

Tags: android, payment-gateway, upi

All payment apps are already available in the both phones but I am getting list size zero:

```
private fun isUPIApp(): Boolean {
        val uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon().build()
        val upiPayIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        upiPayIntent.data = uri

if(packageManager.queryIntentActivities(upiPayIntent, 0).size > 0)
        return true
else
       return false

    }
```